# counting duplicates and assigning label

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel suppose I have a table with the following two columns and following data:

```
ID   Value
1    6
1    2
1    1
2    4
3    5
```

In excel what I would like to do is write the word duplicate in a third column (say result) when the id is duplicate and is not the highest value.

In this example duplicate would be written next to Value(2),ID(1) and Value(1),ID(1). Value(6), ID(1) would not have duplicate written next to it becasue it has the highest value out of all the ID(1)'s.

Is there an excel formula I can use to do this? If not what VBA would I need? In reality this is a large database and there will be more than 3 duplicates.

The result should look like this:

```
ID   Value
1    6
1    2      Duplicate
1    1      Duplicate
2    4
3    5
```

Answer (score 0):

if the duplicates are in column A, the cell B3 could read: (if ID are decreasing)

```
=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A3)>0,"Duplicate #" & COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,A3),"")
```

does this help?

Comment: I dont want to remove duplicates just write the word duplicates in a thrid column. Also I only want the word to be displayed for duplicates with lower value in ID. The duplicate with the max value in ID should not have duplicate displayed.

Comment: Yes, assume that the list is sorted

Comment: @kit you can replace the `;`s with `,`

Comment: I tried: =if(COUNTIF($A$2:$A6,A6,0)>0,"Duplicate #" & COUNTIF($A$2:$A6,A6,0),"") but it gives an error

Comment: @Slai : thanks... goddam french excel... why the hell would they change that?  PS: the  " , 0 " was for sumif, not countif...

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't quite work. Please see my amended question to see what result I am looking for.

Comment: How does it "not quite" work? error? Unexpected behavior? (I modified A3 to A2, that was a mistake. )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct. But please correct me if I am wrong.

```
=IF(MIN($A$2:$A$6 = MIN($B$2:$B$6)), "duplicate", "")
```

Comment: That puts duplicate next to 1,1. not 6,1

Comment: Yes. Value 6 and ID 1 will not have label as duplicate because that value is the highest. That is what you have said in your question. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: ah sorry, the issue is that 2,1 does not also say duplicate

Comment: Is it possible to have not max instead of min or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This array formula should work (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to confirm, though if you have lots of data could be rather slow.

```
=IF(B2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,$B$2:$B$6)),"","Duplicate")
```

Comment: That assigns duplicate to everything except 6,1. I am trying to assign duplicate to only 2,1 and 1,1

Comment: You have to enter the formula by pressing Ctrl and Shift and Enter, not just Enter. Curly brackets will appear round it.

Comment: Thanks this worked. What doest Ctrl Shift enter do and what are the curly brackets for?

Comment: It means Excel evaluates the formula over a range of cells (an array) rather than a single cell. Plenty of links on them, e.g. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7